# Change language in Mac App Store

Tags: mac-app-store

My Mac app only has Chinese localization (due to its special purpose). Currently "Language: English" is shown in the Information column in its Mac App Store page (see the screenshot below). How to change this Language to Chinese (or some other languages)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open the App Store and then scroll down. In the bottom right corner, click on a flag- you'll find the country/language options there! :)

Comment: Thanks, but no, I mean how can I change the supported language (that appears in the Mac App Store) of my app?